# Segmentation Fault with argv when adding an extra argument

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I have a code that tests whether a command is used with the right arguments and, if so, appends it to a file by calling another function.

Below is the code:

```
void main(int argc, char *argv[]){
        char accnum[10];
        char fname[30];
        char lname[30];
        char date[10];
        int amt;
        FILE *q = fopen("bankdata.csv","r");
        if(!q){
                fprintf(stderr,"Error, unable to locate the data file bankdata.csv");
                exit(100);
        }
        if(argc == 1 ){
                 fprintf(stderr,"Error, incorrect usage!\n");
                 fprintf(stderr,"-a ACCTNUM NAME\n");
                 exit(1);
        }
        if(strcmp(argv[1],"-a") == 0){
                if(argc < 4){
                        fprintf(stderr,"Error, incorrect usage!\n");
                        fprintf(stderr,"-a ACCTNUM NAME\n");
                        exit(1);
                }else if(argc > 3){
                        if((sscanf(argv[2], "%s", accnum ) == 1 ) &&
                           (sscanf(argv[3], "%s", fname ) == 1) &&
                           /*(sscanf(argv[4], "%s", lname ) == 1)*/){ //commented out
                                add(accnum,fname/*,lname*/);
                        }
                }
         }
}
void add(char accnum[], char fname[]/*, char lname[]*/){
//      printf("%s, %s, %s", accnum, fname, lname);
        size_t line = 0;
        char buf[100] = "";
        char *term = accnum;
        FILE *fp = fopen ("bankdata.csv", "a+");
        while (fgets (buf, 100, fp)) {     /* read each line */
                if (strstr (buf, term)) {       /* test for term  */
                        fprintf(stderr,"Error, account number %s already exists\n", accnum);
                        fclose(fp);
                        exit(50);
                }
                if (strchr (buf, '\n')) line++; /* increment line */
        }
        fprintf(fp,"AC,%s,%s",accnum,fname);
        fclose(fp);
}
```

So that when I enter

```
./a.out -a 1111 Joe Blow
```

It appends to another file

```
Ac,1111,Joe
```

The problem is, when I try to add the last name (i.e. `uncomment && (sscanf(argv[4], "%s", lname ) == 1))`) and use the same command line (`./a.out -a 1111 Joe Blow`), it gives me a segmentation fault and I don't know why. I also tried uncommenting all the related parts in the add function, but it doesn't change anything.

I think it has something to do with argv[4] being null since that was one of my previous problems when writing the code, but argv[4] should be "blow" right?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: For `argv[4]` to be non-null, `argc` has to be greater than 4, not greater than 3.  And did you modify `fprintf(fp,"AC,%s,%s",accnum,fname);` to emit `lname`?  There's also no need to copy `argv[ n ]` like you do - just pass the arguments directly to your `add()` function:  `add( argv[2], argv[3],...)`.  What you're doing now is susceptible to all kinds of problems if the user enters a too-long string.

Comment: `char *argv[]` is an *array-of-pointers* to nul-terminated strings holding the arguments. The next pointer after the last argument is `NULL` (a *sentinel NULL*). How many arguments do you count in `./a.out -a 1111 Joe Blow` where `./a.out` is the first argument (`argv[0]`) and `"Blow"` is the last argument `argv[4]`.

Comment: Why are you using, e.g. `sscanf(argv[2], "%s", accnum )` when you can simply make your function call as `add (argv[2], argv[3], argv[4]);` without having to duplicate storage of what is already each of the program arguments?

Comment: That code should give you a bunch of warnings, unless you disabled them, because the includes for various standard headers is missing. I guess your real code has them, but then your question lacks a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify this a bit.

Since you work with a fixed number of arguments that need to be there,
first check if there are enough

```
if (argc != 5) 
{
  puts("incorrect number of arguments, syntax: {switch} {accountnumber} {firstname} {lastname}");
  return -1;
}
```

number of arguments is now correct, proceed to check the switch with a switch but first make sure the switch string is long enough

```
if (strlen(argv[2])<2)
{
  puts("switch must be at least two characters long e.g. -a");
  return -2;
}

switch( argv[2][1] )
{
  case 'a':
    add(argv[3],argv[4], argv[5]);  
    break;
  default:
    printf("unrecognized switch %s", argv[2]);
    break;
}  


void add(char* accnum, char* fname, char* lname)
{
  // check arguments for safety
  if (accnum == NULL || fname == NULL || lname == NULL)
  {
    puts("invalid arguments passed to add");
    return;
  }
 ...
```

maybe add some more checks on the arguments like if it is a valid account number and so on.